# Что такое контейнер процедуры в masm

Tags: masm

И как определить отношение макроса к определенному контейнеру?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такого понятия, как "контейнер процедуры" в Масм не существует. дайте больше информации, откуда вы это взяли, может что-то удастся решить.

Comment: Я и не сомневался)) Такая глупость написана в задании лабы по масму